# Dependency installation for Python (Django) project

Tags: django, installation, dependencies, pip, composer-php

I'm new to Python, but I had a requirement at my work-place. Another programmer is developing a project on Python using Django framework, and my task is to find a way in which this project will be executed on any computer.
So, I'm talking about something like Composer for PHP. I need an easiest way that at debian branch to write in terminal a command, that will find some kind of "composer.json" file on the project, will read all the required software, modules, libraries and install it step-by-step on the PC.

Any ideas how to do it in the easiest way? Thanks.

Comment: just a requirements.txt would  be more than enough. Or if you are more ambitious then use docker

Comment: "Any ideas how to do it in the easiest way?" Yes, use [the tool that already exists](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip). Note that searching your exact title would have put you on the right track. So would the Django tutorial, which links to a "how to install Django" page. Please make sure to do basic web searches before asking on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you have not talked about virtual environment, assumed that you already setup the environment and activated it.First get all the libraries lists in requirement.txt file in your project directory by typing below command,

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

when you need to setup project in another system just run this

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

All the dependency will be installed in your project enviornment.

Comment: Just to be sure. My task is to find a solution, that will be easily executed by customer when the project will be finished.
I mean... he downloads the project on his computer, writes at his Ubuntu command that will launch installation of all environments for that project, to be launched and used at the company.

Comment: Are your project running on virtual environment  ?

Comment: At the moment, I don't know how to answer this question. For now they said me that I had to do smth like composer at PHP. Another programmer will make this project on Django, and I need to make easy how all this libraries required by Django project will be installed on the customer's PC. It's a web app...I don't know what else to add. May be Django projects had already instaled smth like "pip" and I can just change the requirements file with my list of libraries and versions, and all will work fine ??

Comment: Ok first do learn some tutorials for installing project with virtual environment, after that you will have an idea about this answer.

Comment: @IuraVarzari You could run pip using `system()` a part of your django initialization.

Answer (score 4):

Using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` is an anti-pattern. It does some things right, such as pinning version numbers, but it can lead to problems with orphan packages later.

I use [pip-tools](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools), this way only your top level dependencies are placed in your `requirements.in` file and then I use `pip-sync` to sync my local environment with pip.

There's a lot more information on pip best practices in my 2016 Pycon UK talk - [Avoiding the "left pad" problem: How to secure your pip install process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qt7TboNJGJg)

Answer (score -3):

in python  there is requirements.text file which take care of the libraries that is used in that project. You should also use the virtualenv

Comment: The requirements file does nothing by itself. Unless you are going to explain how to create, maintain, and install libraries using it this answer isn't very helpful.